# Meteor: large base64 files preventing download

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, gridfs

I am trying to download files that were uploaded from MongoDB using `gridfs`. The download works for small files but does not work for files bigger than `1MB`, no error message no thing happens. Is there a way around the file size issue?

**Event:**

```
Template.form.events({
  "click #chunk": function() {
    let doc = Images.findOne({_id:"TK8mmSg9CvjxwSxE5"});
    let chunk = filenamechunks.find({files_id:new Meteor.Collection.ObjectID(doc.copies.images.key)}).fetch();
    if (chunk.length > 0) {
      let chunksize = 0xffff;
      let len = chunk[0].data.length;
      let strings = [];

      for (var y = 0; y < chunk.length; y++) {
          for (var i = 0; i * chunksize < len; i++){
                    strings.push(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, chunk[y].data.subarray(i * chunksize, (i + 1) * chunksize)));
                };
      };

      let content = btoa(strings.join(''));
      let link = window.document.createElement("a");

      link.setAttribute("href", "data:"+doc.copies.type+";base64," + content);
      link.setAttribute("download", "test."+doc.copies.name.split(".")[1]);
      link.click();
    };
  }
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<template name="form">
    <button id="chunk">click</button>
</template>
```

**Publish:**

```
Meteor.publish("chunks", function(id){
  return filenamechunks.find({files_id:new Meteor.Collection.ObjectID(id)});
});
```

**Subscribe:**

```
Template.form.onCreated(function() {
    this.subscribe("chunks","56fbaa2c850d6b341a0c3344");
});
```

**Packages:**

[image]

Comment: I've encountered the same problem. It's particularly bad on Safari and iOS where you can't programmatically save files. No known workaround on browsers that don't let you save files.